# making MFC/ATL COM application platform Independent

Tags: c++, vba, python-2.7, com, atl

I have a rather huge project that has lot of generic C++ classes, some C++ classes with reference to MFC. The UI is all written is MFC. Application uses ATL / COM to expose objects to scripting languages such as VBA and Python. There are thousands of scripts written in VBA and python.

My next project is to make this application work on many different platforms. However when run on Windows I expect that already existing VBA scripts run.  Any suggestions on what is the best way to approach at this is greatly appreciated. Please suggest programing languages or tools that could be used.If I can make use of existing c++ code base better but not necessary. Scriptable objects need to maintain the same interface as before and they should run with no Or very minimal changes to them. Also is there a easy way to move the scripts written in python 2.7 to python 3.x ?

Comment: Good luck my friend ...

Comment: You're gonna need a lot more than 1000 monkeys with tablets.

Comment: Does the application need to be scriptable across various platforms?  Or does it only need to be scriptable on Windows?  (Incidentally, you're *never* going to be able to run the VBA scripts outside of Windows.)

Comment: Yes I am aware that VBA can only run on Windows. However I do not want to loose that ability to run VBA scripts when run on Windows. I would expect Python scripts to run on various platforms.

Comment: Which platforms do you need to support?  Some platforms (Mac/iOS, for example) *require* certain languages, in which case you're probably better off just reimplementing from scratch, using the existing app as a model.  Other platforms (Linux, Android) can still use C++.  You might want to look at the [Mozilla Application Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_application_framework) as an example.

Comment: Primarily Windows and iOS. Python scripts can run on both. And VB needs to run only on Windows.

Comment: iOS requires objective-C, so you're almost certainly going to have to rewrite.  Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874719/blending-languages-python-and-objective-c) for some tips on merging Python and objective-C.

Comment: I meant to say Mac not iOS sorry. do not expect the App to be running on any mobile devices.